# Can't pass value from JS inside Visualforce Page to Controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, inputcheckboxes

I'm trying to pass a variable from an inputCheckbox from my vfp to my apex controller through js

ApexClass:

```
public void updateAllData(){
    selected = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('selectedAll');
    System.debug('que devuelve el check ' + selected);
    Boolean selectedCheck = !String.isEmpty(selected)?Boolean.valueOF(selected): false;
    for(SelectedQuote selQuo : listQuoteSelected){
        selQuo.selected = selectedCheck;
    }
    System.debug('que devuelve la lista ' + JSON.serialize(listQuoteSelected));
}
```

VFP:

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!updateAllData}" name="CallApexMethod" onComplete="alert('After apex method') ;" reRender="resultTableQuote"/>
    <apex:param name="selectedAll" value=""/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<th class="headerRow">
    <apex:inputCheckbox onchange="myJavascriptFunc(this);"/>
</th>

<script>
    function myJavascriptFunc(data)
    {
        alert('Entered Javascript ' + data.checked) ;
        CallApexMethod(data.checked) ;
    }
</script>
```

But I'm always receiving null in System.debug for selected variable

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Regards,

Comment: I cannot see what `selected` has been initially declared as but if you replace the reference to `selected` with a direct call to `Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('selectedAll')` in your debug statement, do you get the expected output?

Comment: @TSmith selected is initialize as null. I'm going to try that!

Answer (score 1):

There's at least two ways to solve this.

First, you could just use the `assignTo` attribute and skip the extra bits. This is my preferred method, because I don't have to worry about string conversion or other weird tricks.

---

## Apex

```
public transient Boolean selected { get; set; }
```

## Visualforce

```
<apex:param assignTo="{!selected}" name="selectedAll" value=""/>
```

---

Or, you can skip the weird Boolean comparison stuff and just do a simple string check:

```
Boolean selectedCheck = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('selectedAll') == 'true';
```

I'm not sure why this didn't work in your code (we're missing some vital details, I suppose).

---

I wrote an example that demonstrates both uses for you.

---

```
public class q363342 {
    public Boolean selected { get; set; }
    public Boolean selected2 { get; set; }
    public void action() {
        selected2 = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('selectedValue') == 'true';
    }
}
```

---

```
<apex:page controller="q363342">
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:actionFunction name="callToAction" action="{!action}" reRender="form">
            <apex:param assignTo="{!selected}" name="selectedValue" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:inputCheckbox label="Demo" onchange="callToAction(this.checked)" />
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Selected" />
                    <apex:outputText value="{!selected}" />
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Selected 2" />
                    <apex:outputText value="{!selected2}" />
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

Finally, as a side note, notice how I just call the action function directly, rather than calling a method to call the method. This makes it a little more straight-forward, in my opinion.